# DTO mapping exception with entity in ABP

Tags: c#, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

I got an error about "mapping" when I try to insert an entity.

The insert is made by the `Create` method of a CrudAppService.
My entity inherits from `FullAuditedEntity` but the related DTO specifies only a few properties.

How do I handle this situation?

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
==========================================================================
PostDto -> Post (Destination member list)
MaiPiuSprechi.Domain.Posts.Dto.PostDto -> MaiPiuSprechi.Domain.Posts.Post (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Items
IsDeleted
DeleterUser
DeleterUserId
DeletionTime
CreatorUser
LastModifierUser
LastModificationTime
LastModifierUserId
CreationTime
CreatorUserId
```

My DTO:

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Post))]
public class PostDto : EntityDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Scadenza { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Zona { get; set; }
    public TipoPost Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

My entity:

```
[Table("AbpPosts")]
public class Post : FullAuditedEntity<int,User>
{
    public Post()
    {
        // CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Post(string description, string zona)
    {
        Description = description;
        Zona = zona;
    }

    public Post(string description, string zona, TipoPost tipo)
    {
        Description = description;
        Zona = zona;
        Tipo = tipo;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Scadenza { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Zona { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public TipoPost Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Required mapping direction:

> PostDto -> Post (Destination member list)

`[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Post))]` configures `Post -> PostDto` here:

```cs
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Post))]
public class PostDto : EntityDto
```

To configure for both directions, simply do:

```cs
[AutoMap(typeof(Post))]
public class PostDto : EntityDto
```

Comment: Brilliant saved me hours of time. Thanks!!